# Migration generator files tools for nodejs and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

I use nodejs and i have a postgresql database and I'm thinking of using sequelize or db-migration to migrate my existing database. Do you know a way to generate the migration files for my existing database?

Answer (score 0):

**Node.js database migration management for Postgresql**

Here is how to go about it.

There exist a node package manager called **node-pg-migrate**

**install the package using**    npm install node-pg-migrate pg

here is the github URL with code samples.    https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate#node-pg-migrate

Best of Luck